# How to make a Python IRC bot?

Tags: python, bots, irc

I am trying to make a working Python IRC bot for a channel of mine in freenode.
For now all I want it to do is avoid a ping timeout and reply to a '!hi'message with a 'hello!'
I am not placing the bot in a server and I just want it to run for 10-15 minutes from my computer.

The code looks like this: (I have replaced the original channel name and bot name)

```
import socket
import sys

server="irc.freenode.net"
channel="##mychannel"
botnick="testbot"
irc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
irc.connect((server,6667))
irc.send("USER "+botnick+" "+botnick+" "+botnick+" :TestBot\n")
irc.send("NICK "+botnick+"\n")
irc.send("PRIVMSG nickserv :iNOOPE\r\n") #I don't know what this line does....
irc.send("JOIN "+channel+"\n")

while 1:
    text=irc.recv(2040)
    print (text)
    if text.find("PING")!=-1:
        irc.send("PONG "+text.split("PING ")[1]+"\r\n")
    if text.find(":!hi")!=-1:
        irc.send("PRIVMSG "+channel+" :Hello!\r\n")
```

Now when I run the program it says 'couldn't look up your username'. Then after a few seconds it displays some text too fast for me to catch and closes the console. And it doesn't connect to the channel. When I run in IDLE it says " 'str' does not support the buffer interface".

I want to learn to do this so that is why I avoided all the pre existing bots.
And I am not an expert at Python. Javascript-HTML-CSS is my best programming combo.

Can anyone help?

Comment: this is a really, really bad and ridiculously low-level way to write a bot.  i recognize exactly this code, from a dozen other people who've found it online  :)  if you want to learn how this is done, pick apart one of those pre-existing bots.  IRC is not a pleasant protocol to write for (and i say this having written [a basic bot](https://github.com/eevee/dywypi/blob/master/dywypi/dialect/irc/client.py) from scratch).

Comment: (but your actual problem is that you're running this against python 3, whereas it was written for some ancient version of python like 2.2.  it'll probably still work against 2.7, but trust me this is not a good starting point.)

Comment: @Eevee I know. But i'm just starting to learn, and I do not intend it to do anything complicated anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem myself....
It was something wrong with "text.split("PING ")". I changed it to "text.split()" so that it splits at the first whitespace and it works without an issue.